# Is there any way to change the storage size of an existing field containing data?

Tags: 8, entities

There is a site with some nodes and some fields. There is a plain text field already containing data.

It turns out this field length is too small.

Are there fast ways to change its storage type to *text (plain, long)* without losing data?

Comment: Nope. If you would keep the file type and just changed the limit of characters, that's a non-issue but the case you are mentioning is actually change from varchar to text which is a storage schema change. Therefore you would have to create a proper migration of data.

Comment: technically you can but you need to update the sql schema manually, and edit the field settings BLOB for the field manually

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;  We will then know the current limit.  What do you want the field length to be?